# AngularJS Directive - Multiple directives same name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have multiple directives with the same name "parent-elem" (on each page I can have a different number of these directives - dynamic number)

```html
<div ng-app="app">
    <div parent-elem></div>
    <div parent-elem></div>
    <div parent-elem></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to know (inside the link function) AngularJS finished render all the directives with the same name on the page?
Inside the directive link function - how do I know this directive is the last rendered?

Note: Not using a ng-repeat

Comment: If you are making a "reusable directive" or a component, it should be an independent element, that doesn't itself rely upon the state of any other element or the state of the page as a whole.  If your `parent-elem` relies upon knowing if it is the last one to be rendered, it has a design flaw.

Comment: that being said, this *feels like* an [XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  You are asking about a potential solution to a problem that isn't exactly clear.  *why does it matter* if it is the first or the last one rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You should have had written, same directive, multiple times :P

Now, that totally depends on your directive, how you make it.
It can keep the counter in a service or rootScope may be whenever it is initialized.

If you are using ng-repeat which you should in this case, you have a bool $last that can tell you if the element rendered is last or not, which you can pass to the directive via any attribute.